# Single Sign On - Mobile App

Tags: single-sign-on, mobile

We have configured SSO through Azure. Conditional access policy token for this application is configured for 24 hours. Application timeout is set for 2 hours.
The Mobile App stays connected as expected, however, if the Mobile App is closed and re-opened, the user is required to enter their credentials.

Our goal is to be able to cache the credentials and resume the session in the event that the Mobile App is accidentally closed.

are there any settings that can be configure to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

So this, according to the documentation, is not an option for SSO sessions, though it is for other session types as found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_sessions.htm

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ronnie - you reference workstation profile based session experiences. Does the same apply to the mobile app ?

Comment: another question would be if we can configure SSO for workstations and have a different policy for mobile?

Comment: Am pretty sure this is organization wide session settings here. But if using a connected app to connect to a custom interface, you could adjust your session settings there, however i think the same rules would apply for SSO session storage

Comment: With connected app refresh token would be apt for such use case. Here in OAUTH access you can permission the app to request refresh tokens.

Comment: Thanks everyone - am trying to determine if we can have a dual purpose environment
Posted this question for support:
1.Workstation users will utilize a Microsoft Azure link allowing conditional access and SSO through the Azure AD portal.
2.Mobile users will utilize a different URL that allows authentication and MFA through our Duo Proxy authentication server.
Is this possible to do ?

Comment: I am inclined to say yes since you can control access through your connected app separately to enable different authorization. I think you should sandbox test all scenarios to ensure that there aren't conflicts with the SSO and mobile users.